# Can you send iOS push notifications that don't wake up the phone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm wondering if its possible to "alert" push notifications to an iOS device that won't wake up the phone if the screen is turned off.

To be clear, I still want this notification to appear in the lock screen/notifications pull down once the phone is woken up through another method.

Comment: No, that is not possible. At most, you can try sending a push notification that plays a sound but does not display an alert.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, starting in iOS 7, you can send "silent" notifications.

From [iOS 7 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW10):

> Apps supporting either the fetch or remote-notification background modes may be launched or moved from the suspended to background state at appropriate times. In the case of the fetch background mode, the system uses available information to determine the best time to launch or wake apps. For example, it does so when networking conditions are good or when the device is already awake. ***You can also send silent push notifications—that is, notifications that do not display alerts or otherwise disturb the user***.

See also the [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) document, specially the Notification Payload section to see how to send a silent notification.

Comment: I don't think that's what was asked. They want the alert to show up on the lock screen, but they don't want the phone screen to wake up to display it.

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I wanted, I still want the notification to appear in the lock screen when the phone is awoken through other methods.

Comment: @kkshin I don't think you can do that... Silent notifications is as close as it gets.